# Show the mapping is $C^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, gateaux-derivative

I have the following problem:

Suppose $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Let $C([0, 1])$ be the space of continuous functions with norm $||u||_{\infty} = \max_{x \in [0, 1]} |u(x)|$. Show that the map $F: C([0, 1]) \rightarrow C([0, 1])$ defined by $F(u)(x) = f(u(x))$ is $C^1$ and compute its derivative.

It seems pretty simple to show that $F$ is continuous and since $f$ is $C^1$,
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(u+h)(x) - F(u)(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(u(x) + h) - f(u(x))}{h}
$$
tells us that $F$ is $C^1$ also. My questions are:

1) When you compute the derivative by the chain rule you get $\dot F(u)(x) = \dot f(u(x)) \dot u(x)$, but since $C([0, 1])$ is only a space of continuous functions, it's not necessarily true that $u(x)$ will be differentiable. So is my formula wrong?

2) Nowhere did I use the norm given for the problem. This combined with 1) leads me to believe I am missing some major parts of the proof and there is a lot more subtlety involved. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: The derivative of $F$ is a map $C[0,1] \times C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ - you have to specify the direction of differentiation, which will itself be a function! See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A2teaux_derivative.

Comment: Oh ok, I see that now. But then why is the sup-norm important? Is it simply because it makes C([0, 1]) a Banach space?

Comment: the limit in the definition of the derivative requires the space to have a topology. The particular norm doesn't matter; i.e. if you had two topologically equivalent norms they would produce the same derivative.